# HTML onclick JavaScript function call, getting SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, razor

I'm legit confused on why this is occurring for me. I'm trying to call this function in JavaScript using an onclick event handler on a checkbox. Yet, it's throwing a syntax error saying I'm missing a ")". Any suggestions? Only thing I can think of is that "_id" is a keyword of some type.

The basic functionality here is that when a user checks a checkbox, it needs to show the target elements ".fieldCondition". I'm actually using Razor Pages to iterate through a foreach loop that uses a list of property name values to target my elements by their id.

I provided screenshots of the syntax error in Chrome and the compiled Razor Pages HTML.

**Razor Pages**

```
@functions {
    void BuildRules()
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in Fetcher.Survey.Properties) {
            <div class="rule_row">
                <input class="rule_select" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleConditions(@property)" />
                <div class="rule_body">
                    <fieldset class="rule_set">
                        <span>if</span>
                        <input class="fieldName" type="text" value="@property.Name" readonly />
                        <label class="fieldCondition">
                            <input class="radioCondition" type="radio" name="@property.Name" />
                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
                            changes
                        </label>
                        <label class="fieldCondition">
                            <input class="radioCondition" type="radio" name="@property.Name" />
                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
                            is
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

**javascript**

```
$(".fieldCondition").hide();
function toggleConditions(prop) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#condition" + prop.Name).show(300);
    }
    else {
        $("#condition" + prop.Name).hide(200);
    }
};
```

---

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Please add the relevant JS code as text to the question itself.

Comment: I will never understand how creating a bunch of screenshots can be easier than just copy-pasting the code

Comment: excuse my inexperience @Turnip

Comment: thanks @Teemu for the helpful feedback, edits have been made, let me know if there is anything else I can do to make this more clear.

Comment: Here: `onclick="toggleConditions(@property)"`, `@property` is replaced with `System.String _id`, that's not valid expression in Javascript. You've to wrap the argument in quotes (unless the correct id is a pure number) and fix your back-end code to produce a proper `id` instead of back-end language expression (maybe there should be `@property.Id` ..?). The actual error message refers to the space before `_id`.

Comment: Thanks man! Makes sense. Appreciate the help!